# Plausibility of getting a linguistics education when coming from another field entirely?

Tags: syntax

I have a couple questions:

I have a B.S. in Environmental science & policy and a couple publications in the environmental chemistry field. Yet I've come to be really interested in Linguistics and particularly language education. I have fluency in Spanish, and elementary knowledge of German and Hebrew, and a very good general understanding of language. Is it plausible to gain acceptance to a Linguistics or Language Education M.A./Ph.D. program? I am confident of my ability but I don't have "paper-credentials" for language as it were, for the most part.

Perhaps this is not a question actually about linguistics, yet I know the SE community and would really appreciate an answer from people who are serious/experienced in the specific field. If all goes well and I am able to proceed with this interest of mine, I expect I'll be posting in this SE community more often.

Comment: I have removed the opinion-based questions, now it should be better. By the way, being good as a linguistic researcher (for example) has little to do with being a polyglot even if it might help. Linguists in that sense are like scientists, they study the languages rather than gain fluency in them. That's my impression at least.

Comment: Some do, some don't. I know lots of both, and plenty of others on various spectra between. Probly a Master's in some variety you're interested in that has job possibilties (Applied, ESL, Computational, Semantics, ..) would be your most useful educational goal. As for what you need, most PhDs in Linguistics didn't get their linguistic training before grad school; my undergraduate degree was in German and Mathematics. Learn as many languages as you can, natch; but that's not the point -- that's just a job benefit.

Comment: This is up to the discretion of the university you want to apply to. Why not just shoot them an email and ask them if you're eligible for your desired program? That's what I did, with my background in EE.

Comment: @prash ...EE = ?? Enviro-Engineering?

Comment: @khanahk: no, it was Electrical Engineering. To be specific, it was Electronics and Communications Engineering. If you're sending a mail, be sure to write details of your background that will help them look at you favorably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to most post-graduate degrees, it is possible to be accepted to a different field of study from your bachelor's degree. Acceptance usually depends on several factors, including a demonstrable interest in the field, your personal statement, and good recommendation letters. Without having an example of a programme you are thinking of applying to, it is hard to answer your question completely but here is an example of entry requirements for an MA in Linguistics at King's College London:

> 'The programme is particularly suitable for students whose undergraduate degree included a minority of linguistic course units, or who have studied linguistics of a more traditional type elsewhere. It is also suitable for good graduates who have encountered linguistics only indirectly, for instance through psychology, philosophy, or foreign language teaching.'

As long as you are able to demonstrate your interest in your personal statement (your languages should help with this), and have a high-quality bachelor's degree, it is likely that you will be considered for the programme.

I was accepted to an MSc in English Language and Linguistics with an undergraduate degree in English Literature and Politics. My first semester was taught rather than research, and despite the steep learning curve, the structure of the course allowed for little prior knowledge of the subjects.